# Combining logical vector with additional elements to exclude

Tags: r

I'm calculating a logical vector of columns in a matrix that I want to use to look at a subset of the data. How would I combine

```
duplicate.ids <- c(1, 10, 100)
```

with

```
data$Group == data$Group[person] & data$Unit != 13 & data$Unit != 17
```

to get one logical vector I could use?

ETA:

I've got a matrix of values:

```
R> class(All)
[1] "matrix"
R> dim(All)
[1] 6712 6712
R> All[1:5,1:5]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I have another matrix of metadata about each of the columns, and I want to select a subset of this matrix for further analysis. I can run the second command to get a logical vector that I can then use to get a subset

```
All[,data$Group == data$Group[person] & data$Unit != 13 & data$Unit != 17]
```

but I also want to exclude a specific list of indexes (the duplicate.ids I referenced earlier).

Comment: The second code block will return row indices, but you just say that you are calculating a logical vector of columns. Are you asking how you can subset using both row and column indices? Can you elaborate/clarify?

Comment: 1. I think you have a `data.frame` rather than a matrix. 2. are you assigning that to something? 3. what do you want to do with the `duplicate.ids`? and which column do you want to do it to?  Maybe including a portion of `data` using `dput(head(data))` would help us understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could turn your logical vector into a vector of indices using `which`, and then use `setdiff` to compute the set difference, i.e. all columns selected by the second expression which are not in the list of duplicates.

Taken together:

```
All[,setdiff(which(data$Group == data$Group[person] & data$Unit != 13 & data$Unit != 17),
             duplicate.ids)]
```

As an alternative, you could turn `duplicate.ids` into a logical vector as well:

```
non.duplicate <- rep(TRUE, ncol(All))
non.duplicate[duplicate.ids] <- FALSE
ALL[,non.duplicate & data$Group == data$Group[person] & data$Unit != 13 & data$Unit != 17]
```